# fixed length data types in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

I've heard that size of data types such as `int` may vary across platforms.

My first question is: can someone bring some example, what goes wrong, when program
assumes an `int` is 4 bytes, but on a different platform it is say 2 bytes?

Another question I had is related. I know people solve this issue with some `typedefs`,
like you have variables like `u8`,`u16`,`u32` - which are guaranteed to be 8bits, 16bits, 32bits, regardless of the platform -- my question is, how is this achieved usually? (I am not referring to types from `stdint` library - I am curious manually, how can one enforce that some type is always say 32 bits regardless of the platform??)

Comment: There are potential issues with overwriting memory. If you are assuming that an integer is 4 bytes when it's 2 bytes on another platform, depending on how the memory is laid out, you could overwrite the next 2 bytes after your integer.

Comment: a good time to read the (old, but still hugely informative) C FAQ from Usenet days : http://www.faqs.org/faqs/C-faq/abridged/ and then http://www.faqs.org/faqs/C-faq/faq/ (unabridged, so if you can read that one instead! many more infos). It talks about many of those, and also about many other often-wrong assumptions (internal representation of NULL, etc). (A must read is the chapter about null, and about pointers/arrays. The rest is GOOD too, and eye-opening on many subjects)

Comment: Please note that the byte ordering might also vary from platform to platform. (+1 for question - it's better to ask question then assume "surely the `sizeof(void *)` will always be `4`).

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka: agreed. and it's good to post those, as many reader could then become aware of the potential pitfall and of its solutions! There are no bad questions [well, if they give enough context], just bad answers ^^

Answer (score 42):

> I know people solve this issue with some typedefs, like you have variables like u8,u16,u32 - which are guaranteed to be 8bits, 16bits, 32bits, regardless of the platform

There are some platforms, which have no types of certain size (like for example TI's 28xxx, where size of char is 16 bits). In such cases, it is not possible to have an 8-bit type (unless you really want it, but that may introduce performance hit).

> how is this achieved usually?

Usually with typedefs. c99 (and c++11) have [these typedefs in a header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer). So, just use them.

> can someone bring some example, what goes wrong, when program assumes an int is 4 bytes, but on a different platform it is say 2 bytes?

The best example is a communication between systems with different type size. Sending array of ints from one to another platform, where sizeof(int) is different on two, one has to take extreme care.

Also, saving array of ints in a binary file on 32-bit platform, and reinterpreting it on a 64-bit platform.

Comment: +1 for _saving array of ints in a binary file on 32-bit platform, and reinterpreting it on a 64-bit platform._.

Answer (score 22):

In earlier iterations of the C standard, you generally made your own `typedef` statements to ensure you got a (for example) 16-bit type, based on `#define` strings passed into the compiler for example:

```
gcc -DINT16_IS_LONG ...
```

Nowadays (C99 and above), there are specific types such as `uint16_t`, the exactly 16-bit wide unsigned integer.

Provided you include `stdint.h`, you get exact bit width types,at-least-that-width types, fastest types with a given minimum widthand so on, as documented in `C99 7.18 Integer types <stdint.h>`. If an implementation has compatible types, they are required to provide these.

Also very useful is `inttypes.h` which adds some other neat features for format conversion of these new types (`printf` and `scanf` format strings).

Comment: Sub question: If the platform does not support a 16 bit integer type is `unint16_t` not defined in `cstdint` etc..? Or does the standard guarantee that type will always be there (and do stuff internally to make sure it works)?

Comment: No, the C standard only _requires_ it if the implementation has a compatible type. If you're running on a 12-bit DSP for example, then it doesn't _have_ to provide a 16-bit uint16_t. It _may_ but it's not mandatory: `7.18.1.1/3: These types are optional. However, if an implementation provides integer types with widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits, and (for the signed types) that have a
two’s complement representation, it shall define the corresponding typedef names.`

Comment: So if you use `uint16_t` and the platform does not support it then we can expect a compilation error during the porting processes.

Comment: @Loki, yes, the compiler won't know the type.

Answer (score 16):

For the first question: [Integer Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

For the second question: for example, to `typedef` an unsigned 32 bits integer, on a platform where `int` is 4 bytes, use:

```
 typedef unsigned int u32;
```

On a platform where `int` is 2 bytes while `long` is 4 bytes:

```
typedef unsigned long u32;
```

In this way, you only need to modify one header file to make the types cross-platform.

If there are some platform-specific macros, this can be achieved without modifying manually:

```
#if defined(PLAT1)
typedef unsigned int u32;
#elif defined(PLAT2)
typedef unsigned long u32;
#endif
```

If C99 `stdint.h` is supported, it's preferred.

Comment: Never mind, there are such times ... - have a break!

Comment: What is a platform here? Is it the hardware - like x86, x86_64, AMD etc... or is it an operating system - like Solaris, AIX, HP-UX, Linux, macOS, BSD, and IBM z/OS etc... ?

Answer (score 8):

First of all: Never write programs that rely on the width of types like `short`, `int`, `unsigned int`,....

Basically: "never rely on the width, if it isn't guaranteed by the standard".

If you want to be truly platform independent and store e.g. the value 33000 as a signed integer, you *can't* just assume that an `int` will hold it. An `int` has at least the range `-32767` to `32767` or `-32768` to `32767` (depending on ones/twos complement). That's just not enough, even though it *usually* is 32bits and therefore capable of storing 33000. For this value you definitively need a `>16bit` type, hence you simply choose `int32_t` or `int64_t`. If this type doesn't exist, the compiler will tell you the error, but it won't be a silent mistake.

Second: C++11 provides a standard header for fixed width integer types. None of these are guaranteed to exist on your platform, but when they exists, they are guaranteed to be of the exact width. See [this article on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint) for a reference. The types are named in the format `int[n]_t` and `uint[n]_t` where `n` is `8`, `16`, `32` or `64`. You'll need to include the header `<cstdint>`. The `C` header is of course `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: OP: "_I am not referring to types from stdint library - I am curious manually, how can one enforce that some type is always say 32 bits regardless of the platform??)_";

Comment: @legends2k The correct way to have fixed width integer types _is_ using standard libraries.

Comment: Agreed, but that's when you write code, not when you try to learn how such headers are written in the first place.

Comment: @legends2k Well that's just platform dependent. If one is interested in that: Just open the header ;-)

Comment: "*First of all: Never write programs that rely on the width of types.*" so you're saying we should not rely on `uint32_t` being 32 bits wide? Abstractions are nice and all but eventually there comes a point where you need to make some assumptions to actually get anything done.

Comment: What do you mean, 'never write programs that rely on the width of types'?  The width of types directly affects the range of possible values, and that is very important when choosing what types to use, especially for the kind of programming tasks that many people use C/C++ for.  If you're writing a filesystem or anything that needs to store a lot of values in constrained memory, you need to make those kinds of decisions.  There is a reason strings aren't stored as arrays of unsigned long long.

Comment: -1, it's impossible not to rely on the width of every type you use. It is necessary to be aware what the numeric limits are and request sufficient ranges. If you are worried about the existence of exact-width types, use `uintmin[n]_t` and `uintfast[n]_t` types.

Comment: @Thomas, tfinniga and Potatoswatter: Sorry for beeing unclear about that. I meant to write "don't rely on width of `short`, `int`,... but falsely didn't specify. That's corrected now.

Comment: @legends2k: yes exactly as you mention I was interested mainly to see how such headers are written in the first place. I think out of the responses I get the picture. One could use `#ifdef` to see which platform code is being run, and then based on that, he/she can use for example `typedef int u32` or `typedef short u32` for example, right? but this means in advance you must know on which platform which type has what size

Comment: @dmcr_code: The example you stated is correct. Of course, you should know what you're targetting. Say tomorrow you are porting your code to some exotic platform which has char as 32-bits, you'll modify the header with a new typedef. These things help you write portable code, but not _absolute_ portable code i.e. any code will have some porting work involved when you move to a new platform, these things will minimize the effort.

Comment: Think of realtime DSP! You really want to fit the fixed point arithmetics of yours to the native bit widths the processor/MCU can handle. Otherwise you will need additional clocks to complete an arithmetic operation, and that results in poorer performance, and ultimately a failing design, e.g. in closed-loop control applications.

Answer (score 6):

usually, the issue happens when you max out the number or when you're serializing.  A less common scenario happens when someone makes an explicit size assumption.

In the first scenario:

```
int x = 32000;
int y = 32000;
int z = x+y;        // can cause overflow for 2 bytes, but not 4
```

In the second scenario,

```
struct header {
int magic;
int w;
int h;
};
```

then one goes to fwrite:

```
header h;
// fill in h
fwrite(&h, sizeof(h), 1, fp);

// this is all fine and good until one freads from an architecture with a different int size
```

In the third scenario:

```
int* x = new int[100];
char* buff = (char*)x;


// now try to change the 3rd element of x via buff assuming int size of 2
*((int*)(buff+2*2)) = 100;

// (of course, it's easy to fix this with sizeof(int))
```

If you're using a relatively new compiler, I would use uint8_t, int8_t, etc.  in order to be assure of the type size.

In older compilers, typedef is usually defined on a per platform basis.  For example, one may do:

```
 #ifdef _WIN32
      typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
      typedef unsigned short uint16_t;
      // and so on...
 #endif
```

In this way, there would be a header per platform that defines specifics of that platform.

Comment: +1 for being the first to mention structs. You should also be aware of what happens when you send a strct over the network.

Answer (score 5):

> I am curious manually, how can one enforce that some type is always say 32 bits regardless of the platform??

If you want your (modern) C++ program's compilation to fail if a given type is not the width you expect, add a `static_assert` somewhere. I'd add this around where the assumptions about the type's width are being made.

```
static_assert(sizeof(int) == 4, "Expected int to be four chars wide but it was not.");
```

`chars` on most commonly used platforms are 8 bits large, but not all platforms work this way.

Comment: `sizeof` actually returns size in `char`s, not bytes. So if you want to check size in *bits*, you should do `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT == 32`.

Comment: static_assert is only available in the latest standard. But uint_32t, and similar types are available from before

Comment: @user694733 No. Size in chars = size in bytes, by definition. `sizeof(char)==1` – always.

Comment: @sammy Nope, `uint32_t` etc. were added at the same time as `static_assert`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It depends on the definition of the byte. Byte is usually considered to be 8 bits. `char` always has `CHAR_BIT` bits. `CHAR_BIT` is at least 8, but may be more.

Comment: @user694733 No, it doesn’t. The standard says, literally, that “`sizeof(char)` … [is] 1”, and “The `sizeof` operator yields the number of bytes in the object representation of its operand” (§5.3.3). This is all that matters. The value of `CHAR_BIT` is irrelevant in this. If `CHAR_BIT==16`, that simply means that on this machine, a byte has 16 bits.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I am not denying that. But if you must know how many **bits** type has, you have to take `CHAR_BIT` into consideration too, because `sizeof(type)` returns how many `char`s the `type` is.

Comment: @user694733 That’s a fair point. I actually just replied to the first part of your first comment.

Answer (score 3):

Well, first example - something like this:

```
int a = 45000; // both a and b 
int b = 40000; // does not fit in 2 bytes.
int c = a + b; // overflows on 16bits, but not on 32bits
```

If you look into `cstdint` header, you will find how all fixed size types (`int8_t`, `uint8_t`, etc.) are defined  - and only thing differs between different architectures is this header file. So, on one architecture `int16_t`could be:

```
 typedef int int16_t;
```

and on another:

```
 typedef short int16_t;
```

Also, there are other types, which may be useful, like: `int_least16_t`

Answer (score 2):

1. If a type is smaller than you think then it may not be able to store a value you need to store in it.
2. To create a fixed size types you read the documentation for platforms to be supported and then  define `typedef`s based on `#ifdef` for the specific platforms.

Answer (score 2):

> > can someone bring some example, what goes wrong, when program assumes an int is 4 bytes, but on a different platform it is say 2 bytes?

Say you've designed your program to read 100,000 inputs, and you're counting it using an `unsigned int` assuming a size of 32 bits (32-bit unsigned ints can count till 4,294,967,295). If you compile the code on a platform (or compiler) with 16-bit integers (16-bit unsigned ints can count only till 65,535) the value will wrap-around past 65535 due to the capacity and denote a wrong count.

Answer (score 1):

Compilers are responsible to obey the standard. When you include `<cstdint>` or `<stdint.h>` they shall provide types according to standard size.

Compilers know they're compiling the code for what platform, then they can generate some internal macros or magics to build the suitable type. For example, a compiler on a 32-bit machine generates `__32BIT__` macro, and previously it has these lines in the `stdint` header file:

```
#ifdef __32BIT__
typedef __int32_internal__ int32_t;
typedef __int64_internal__ int64_t;
...
#endif
```

and you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

bit flags are the trivial example. 0x10000 will cause you problems, you can't mask with it or check if a bit is set in that 17th position if everything is being truncated or smashed to fit into 16-bits.