# Does c++11 have something like quint8?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qtcore

There are some types in Qt, for example quint8 that is guaranteed to be 8-bit on all platforms supported by Qt.

I am wondering if C++11 has such kind of type? if not, what is the alternative for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can types defined in [stdint.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/) solve this problem?

Comment: Yes it does check http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/

Comment: This has to be a duplicate of _something_.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: If searching for the question doesn't turn up anything, try searching for the obvious answer. I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237451/fixed-length-data-types-in-c-c

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, C++11 adds types with more precisely defined sizes. Here's [the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint).

They are defined in `<cstdint>`.

You are guaranteed to have these:

```
intmax_t        uintmax_t

int_least8_t    uint_least8_t
int_least16_t   uint_least16_t
int_least32_t   uint_least32_t
int_least64_t   uint_least64_t

int_fast8_t     uint_fast8_t
int_fast16_t    uint_fast16_t
int_fast32_t    uint_fast32_t
int_fast64_t    uint_fast64_t
```

You may or may not have these:

```
int8_t          uint8_t 
int16_t         uint16_t
int32_t         uint32_t
int64_t         uint64_t

intptr_t        uintptr_t
```

Explanations:

- The `u` prefix means unsigned.
- The `least` variants are the smallest integer types available with at least that width.
- The `fast` variants are the fastest integer types available with at least that width.
- The `intptr` variants are guaranteed to be convertible to `void*` and back.
- The `max` variants are the largest available types.

Comment: what does fast really mean?

Comment: @camino: "At least as fast as any other integer type with at least the specified width."

Comment: @camino That the type only guarantees a certain minimum length, but if on the given platform a longer type is "faster" to deal with, it will be used instead.

Comment: The `intprt` variants are not *compatible* with `void*`; type compatibility is a much stronger condition. The guarantee is that converting a `void*` value to `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` and back to `void*` yields the original `void*` value (i.e., there's no loss of information). Both types are optional.

Comment: From what I know, compilers aren't guaranteed to have those. They are only required to have `typedef`s of those form, not those specifically. Unless something has changed in the standard.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: That is correct, but do you think that matters for OP?

Comment: I'm saying your claim that "you are _guaranteed_ to have" (emphasis mine) is wrong.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: You are guaranteed to have a typename in `<cstdint>` with each of those names. I'm not saying that they are separate types, just that they are present and can be used. I don't think it's relevant whether it's a separate type or a `typedef`, but maybe I'm missing your point?

Comment: What I personally do not understand in this answer is the brain dump of all the types instead of just focusing on the question of quint*8*. I think from the question's point of view, all the rest is red-herring and needless noise. Also, it is worth noting, as per my answer, that this will not work on all the platforms that Qt supports.

Comment: @FinalContest: I respectfully disagree, and read the quint*8*-part as an example rather than the complete list of what he needs. Besides, listing all types is more useful for future googlers. Since OP explicitly asks if C++11 adds support for such types, I presume that he is aware of the limitation and has support for C++11.

Comment: The question was `Does c++11 have something like quint8?`. If someone asks about shared pointers, you do not start talking about the scoped, unique, auto, weak, borrowed and other pointers because the majority of that would be red-herring, and hence the signal/noise ratio is very low to get the useful information out. What people usually do on SO if they want to provide details is to give a link to the further details. How max or intptr is relevant to quint8 or even quint16/32/64, I do not know. (Btw, the OP is also saying "type similar to quint8' and "all platforms suppoted by Qt")

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [it does, and even more](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer). From the documentation:

```
uint8_t unsigned integer type with width of 8
uint_fast8_t fastest unsigned integer type with width of 8
uint_least8_t smallest unsigned integer type with width of at least 8
```

Disclaimer: this will not obviously work on platforms where Qt is supported and does not have C++11. If you plan to support those, stick with your `quint8`, otherwise go drop it in favor of modern C++.

Make sure you will have this in your qmake project file to actually enable C++11:

```
CONFIG += c++11
```